# Large Deviations: Exponential decay in normed spaces

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, it.information-theory, measure-concentration

Let $(X_1,X_2,\cdots)$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables taking values in some general normed space $(V,||\cdot||)$. Denote $\mu=E[X_1]$ and $S_n=\frac{1}{n}[X_1+\cdots+X_n]$.

This question is about the tail probability $Pr[||S_n-\mu||\geq\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ and I am especially concerned with the question if the tail probability decays to exponentially fast in $n$.

Is $||X_i||\leq\tau$, $\tau \in (0,\infty)$ sufficient for Hoeffdings's Inequallity to hold with
$$
Pr[||S_n-\mu||\geq\epsilon]\leq \exp\left(-n^2\epsilon^2c \right),
$$
where $c>0$ is some finite constant?

Comment: There is a Banach-space version of Azuma's inequality due to Assaf Naor, theorem 1.5 in  [https://web.math.princeton.edu/~naor/homepage%20files/AR-notes.ps]. There you need however special properties of the norm (*modulus of smoothness of power type 2*).